# Xampp localhost index does not open

Tags: php, windows, xampp, hosts

i am having a problem with my xampp. Whenever i try to open my localhost, a project that i have opens. Actually i was learning laravel so i changed my system32/drivers/tec/host code into this. So do i have a problem here.

```
  # Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   127.0.1.2      hariyalihost.dev
#    
#   ::1             localhost
#   ::2     hariyalihost

127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.2   hariyalihost.dev
```

Comment: Why are you mapping that in HOSTS?  Just create another folder in your XAMPP `htdocs` folder and work from there.  Anything in the `127` network will bring you right back to `localhost` - the whole network is reserved as the loopback.  If you want to see it, ping any address in there and you will get a response.

Comment: actually i was learning laravel and i was trying to use pretty url in this way as one of the tutorial showed. So now i cannot open my localhost and yes i do have my work reserved in htdocs folder. I just cant find out why instead of my localhost, the project folder opens

Comment: Have you tried removing all entries from your HOSTS file?  Once Apache is up and running in XAMPP, a link to `http://localhost/` should point to whatever is in your `htdocs` directory.  When I am developing in XAMPP I usually make a directory as a domain name and then access it via `http://localhost/example.com/`.  I am not familiar with Larvel though, so it is very possible there is something else in play I am unaware of...